# How would I write numpy.tensordot in c++?

Tags: c++, numpy, convolution, tensordot

I'm trying to replicate numpy.tensordot in c++. The example in the numpy documentation shows a nested loop that I can get to work, but what if instead of

```
c = np.tensordot(a,b, axes=([1,0],[0,1]))
```

I want to do:

```
c = np.tensordot(a,b, axes=([1,2],[0,1]))
```

What would that new nested loop look like in python?  And is there an easier/faster way of doing this operation in c++? Right now I'm using the same nested "for" loops with std::vector's in c++. I've seen a few libraries that might help, but I'm trying to use just the c++ standard library.

Here is that numpy example, and the link to the documentation: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html

```
Examples

A “traditional” example:

>>>
a = np.arange(60.).reshape(3,4,5)
b = np.arange(24.).reshape(4,3,2)
c = np.tensordot(a,b, axes=([1,0],[0,1]))
c.shape
(5, 2)
c
array([[4400., 4730.],
       [4532., 4874.],
       [4664., 5018.],
       [4796., 5162.],
       [4928., 5306.]])
# A slower but equivalent way of computing the same...
d = np.zeros((5,2))
for i in range(5):
  for j in range(2):
    for k in range(3):
      for n in range(4):
        d[i,j] += a[k,n,i] * b[n,k,j]
c == d
array([[ True,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True,  True]])
```

Thank you

Comment: `np.tensordot` is a complicated front end to `np.dot`.  Based on the `axes` values it transforms the inputs with `reshape` and `transpose`, reducing the problem to a simple 2d `dot`.  It may then transform the result back.  I'm sure there c++ libraries that already implement the basic matrix multiplication (which must also depend on what array library you are using).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Do you know the operations it would take with  reshape, transpose, and dot,  for the ```np.tensordot(a,b, axes=([1,2],[0,1]))``` example? Given two 3D arrays.

Comment: Not off the top of my head.  I'd have to take some time to experiment and read code.  I prefer to use `np.einsum` and `np.matmul/@`.  `tensordot` is a relic from the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find rewriting to `np.einsum` first is helpful as the resulting for loop code looks quite similar conceptually:

```py
a = np.random.rand(16, 8, 2)
b = np.random.rand(8, 2, 1)


c =  np.tensordot(a, b, axes=([1,2],[0,1]))

# same thing written with einsum
c_ein = np.einsum("ijk,jko->io", a, b)

# same thing done with for loops, 
# notice how we can use the same letters and indexing as einsum
c_manual = np.zeros((16, 1))
for i in range(16):
    for o in range(1):
        # j and k are summed since they don't appear in output
        total = 0
        for j in range(8):
            for k in range(2):
                total += a[i, j, k] * b[j, k, o]
        c_manual[i, o] = total

assert np.allclose(c, c_ein, c_manual)
```

Comment: Thanks again! I haven't ported to c++ yet but I suspect it will be pretty easy. I'll post back once I get that working, but it looks like that's everything I'll need.  I'll use einsum from now on.